# git) unable to read file ~ that is a actually a directory

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I had an issue with handling github reposit in vscode.
which is "error: Unable to open 'src (Working Tree)': Unable to read file '~' that is actually a directory"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out that folder location.

If you are using window OS, fix it to show all hide files from your directory settings.

and you can check another your **'.git' files**.
delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by running:

```
git rm --cached -r
```

After that I staged all changes and the file that was causing trouble could be pushed as deleted.